# jQuery - ColorBox new window issues

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I love colorbox, but I have been running in to a couple of issues that I would like to try to get resolved.

1) When you right click a link - open link in new window, it displays the colorbox link in a new window and I lose my entire layout.  Is there any way to check if the link is being opened in a new window, and if so, display a different page that has the full layout of the website?

2) The same thing happens when you click a colorbox link and the parent page is completely loaded yet.  It automatically opens the colorbox link like a normal link and I lose my entire layout again.

Has anyone ran in to these issues? If so, have you been able to resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. It appeared to be a validation error in my page. Check if your page meets the web standards / validates. Especially scripts-related lines.